# Встречается ТОКО и ТОКА вместо слова ТОЛЬКО

Tags: грамматика

Часто в комментариях встречается слово ТОКА и ТОКО вместо слова ТОЛЬКО. Меня это раздражает. Может я что-то пропустила и по-современному это не является безграмотностью? Школу я заканчивала более 40 лет назад.

Answer (score 1):

Это передача устной речи. Подобные слова в иронических текстах вполне естественны (можно, например, в "Левше" Лескова найти), но если автор претендует на серьезность - явно неуместны.

Answer (score 0):

Это просторечная разговорная форма. В литературе имеет право только в качестве прямой речи персонажа.